# In c, are user-defined functions code loaded into text segment of memory when they are called?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, operating-system

(sorry for my bad english)

In c, are all the user-defined functions code loaded into text segment of memory at once during program startup or only main function is loaded and all the other user-defined functions code are loaded into text segment when it is called?

Comment: That's not specified by the language. Either method is fine, and both methods are used.

Comment: As an additional complication, mapping a region of a file into virtual memory doesn't equate to loading it--it could be that *pages* of program code are loaded as they are accessed (meaning that if a function spanned two pages, it would not be loaded all at the same time)

Comment: And this is not a specialty of C. A program can be written in any programming language, and sometimes you can't decide by the executable code.